# WatiN error: cannot load

Tags: watin

I am working on a new test project with watiN, but always get this error,

Could not load file or assembly 'WatiN.Core, Version=2.0.3.913, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db7cfd3acb5ad44e' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.

Did I miss something? thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The assembly appears to be strongly named so you can install it in the GAC (open C:\windows\assembly and drag the dll into there). You may need to download it from the internet if you can't find it on your computer.

Failing that, are you on a 64 bit computer? It may be that watin requires you to execute your program as a 32 bit application (In Visual Studio, this is under the "Build Configuration" section).

Comment: You are right. I changed the platform target to x86 and it's working. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you needs to run WatiN in 64 bit , you can get the source and change the target platform to x64 in the project properties.Rebuild the project and reference the new 64 bit WatiN.Core.It should work.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to add a reference in your project to the WatiN assembly?  Or possibly copy the WatiN assembly to your /bin folder?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add - if you can't/don't want to recompile your Watin project for 32bit  and it was compiled using 32bit and you want to run it in 64bit environment, you need to change it's header flags to use 32 bit.

This is done by issuing the following command:

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\Bin\CorFlags.exe" /32BIT+ myWatinProg.exe
```

The corFlags command is part of windows SDK on 64 bit platform.

(Taken from http://sourceforge.net/projects/watintestrecord/forums/forum/682552/topic/3229029)